# Why is my SQL query not using the index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, plpgsql

This is my query:

```
explain analyze SELECT levenshtein('google', lower(s."Name"), 2, 2, 1), d."Domain"
FROM   analyst_sld s, analyst_domain d
WHERE  levenshtein('google', lower(s."Name"), 2, 2, 1) < 4 AND s.id = d."SLDk_id"
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This is the output:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=5340874.17..5383497.72 rows=17049420 width=46) (actual time=136245.943..138709.585 rows=1022346 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (levenshtein('google'::text, lower((s."Name")::text), 2, 2, 1))
   Sort Method:  external sort  Disk: 78656kB
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=122111.24..1195078.39 rows=17049420 width=46) (actual time=16730.865..133020.419 rows=1022346 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (d."SLDk_id" = s.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on analyst_domain d  (cost=0.00..417631.20 rows=17049420 width=38) (actual time=0.036..64677.170 rows=17041042 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=103151.93..103151.93 rows=1090665 width=16) (actual time=16730.443..16730.443 rows=1071 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on analyst_sld s  (cost=0.00..103151.93 rows=1090665 width=16) (actual time=14.742..16726.358 rows=1071 loops=1)
                     Filter: (levenshtein('google'::text, lower(("Name")::text), 2, 2, 1) < 4)
 Total runtime: 139557.853 ms
```

Why does it not use an index, but a sequential scan?
Also, what does the "Hash Join" and "Hash Cond" mean?

EDIT_1:
Indexes:

```
                                      Table "public.analyst_domain"
     Column     |           Type           |                          Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 ID             | integer                  | not null default nextval('analyst_domain_id_seq'::regclass)
 Domain         | character varying(255)   | not null
 SLDk_id        | integer                  |
Indexes:
    "analyst_domain_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("ID")
    "analyst_domain_Domain_key" UNIQUE, btree ("Domain")
    "analyst_domain_sldk" btree ("SLDk_id")



                                      Table "public.analyst_sld"
     Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('analyst_sld_id_seq'::regclass)
 Name           | character varying(255)   | not null
Indexes:
    "analyst_sld_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "analyst_sld_Name_key" UNIQUE, btree ("Name") CLUSTER
    "analyst_sld_upper_idx" btree (upper("Name"::text))
```

Comment: What do your indexes look like?

Comment: Can you add the table definition to the post? We need the index definition as well.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a sequential scan on analyst_sld because that's the only way to do the levenshtein filtering. If you think that is a significant filter, you can

```
CREATE INDEX lev_index on 
 analyst_sld (levenshtein('google', lower("Name"), 2, 2, 1));
```

As far as the hash goes: Postgres has decided that the best way to join your tables is by looking for equal hashes on the join column (and resolving them in case the buckets have more than one entry). How many elements do your tables have, and how large do you expect the join to be?

Answer (score 1):

As to the DDL: in pgAdmin III - when you select an object (table/index/etc) in the tree the DDL will show in the window to the right.

The DDL would allow a better answer than the assumption based guess below.

As to the reason, with the information given and assuming primary key index on the join criteria, here is my GUESS: d is ~17 times larger than s, s is being filtered on a function which is not indexed, so the optimizer has no idea on the selectiveness of that filter. Which is quicker an index scan with row lookups for s.name or a sequential scan? Sequential wins according to the optimizer.

Comment: d is ~17 times larger than s.

Comment: @alfonzo1955: Without knowing the distribution of the SLDk_id (e.g. how many are NULL, or is there another predominant value), let's assume it is a nice even distribution; in other words: there is a row in d for each row in s. As the optimizer has no idea on how many rows the levenshtein function is going to eliminate, it _probably_ reasons worst case scenario: all rows join. Reading the index entry for each row, and then the name for each row from the actual table, is slower than simply scanning the whole table, especially when d is so narrow (<256 bytes for name + 4 or so bytes for id)

Comment: Sorry, it should read "...especially when **s** is so narrow ..." Caught it after the 5 minute edit window.

Comment: So is there any way to force it to use an index?

Comment: There are a few things you can consider:
1) Are the tables and indexes analyzed? I.e. did we give the optimizer all the information we can give it?

Comment: 2) If scanning the table is faster, do we want it to use the index?

I think this is where the query is at. The integer id as an extra in the full table scan is such a small overhead compared the index scan and then reading the table blocks for the rows touched.

We just need to make sure the system has all the information it needs to make the best decision.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a PostgreSQL expert by far, it looks like it's using a aequential scan due to the use of the levenshtein function. I don't know the specifics of this function, but usually one can create an index based on a function evaluation; however I hazard to guess that the "Google" string is variable in your case, so I don't know how useful an index would be...

Comment: It is doing a sequential to match s.id and d."SLDk_id" which should not be happening.

Comment: Oh, indeed! I was looking at the inside loop first. Without the table structure and the index list there's not much more anyone can do...